# how to get a username in firestore from another collection with angularfire

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, observable, angularfire

how to get a username in firestore from another collection with angularfire

I have 2 collections

```
-users
--username
--uid
```

and

```
-post
--title
--user_id
```

**How to get the username when displaying all posts?**

I could only return the user_id

Comment: It seems to me that you wanted a relational behavior using Firestore, if I understood properly. As explained by @Renaud Tarnec, you would need to have that information in your `post` collection, since it is not possible to do something like a relational `JOIN`.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't share your existing code for displaying all posts, so it is difficult to give your the exact code to add...

But, basically, you have two options:

### Lookup the username in the users collection

Before displaying a `post`, you do an extra query to the database to get the value of the `username`, like `afs.collection('users', ref => ref.where('uid', '==', 'user_id))` (See https://github.com/angular/angularfire/blob/master/docs/firestore/querying-collections.md)

This implies **an extra read** for each post you display

### Save the username together with the userid when you save the post document

This is a classical approach in the NoSQL world: you denormalize your data in such a way your query is easy to build and execute.

More concretely it means that your posts collection would be like:

```
-post
--title
--user_id
--username
```

However, this is only possible if you have, in your front-end, the value of `username` when you write the `post` document. One classical way is to get it from the [`currentuser`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth.html#currentuser) object, via `currentuser.displayname`.

One side effect of this approach is that you need to keep the values in sync (i.e. the one in the `user` document and the ones in the `post` document**s**) . However, in your specific case, we can probably make the assumption that the username is not going to change very frequently...

---

You should not be afraid to duplicate data and denormalize your data model. Here is a "famous" post about NoSQL data-modelling approaches: https://highlyscalable.wordpress.com/2012/03/01/nosql-data-modeling-techniques/